# Realm accessed from incorrect thread. iOS Best Practice

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I used to work with Realm a long time ago, but it's the first time to face this crash

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Realm accessed from incorrect thread.'
```

After some search, I found out solutions about creating a new instance everytime you want to work with inside another Queue.

```
 backgroundQueue.async {
    print("Dispatched to background queue")
    let realm = try! Realm()
     ....
```

Seems to be not efficient to create new instance everytime and also in background queue so I have to adjust my code to that.
Is there any way to solve that?

The awkward thing is that I made sure that creating the instance and calling it both happen on the main thread!!!

Comment: Use a class variable.

Comment: There are few ways: Convert them to normal object, recreate Realm and refetch, or use `ThreadSafeReference`

Comment: I'm already using a class variable (in super class). But I got the issue. The realm instance was called twice as each of the child class call the parent init!

Comment: Don't pass managed RealmObject and RealmResults between threads.

Comment: Why are you creating a realm in a background queue as shown in the question? What's the use case? Realm caches instances on a per-thread basis, so there's almost no overhead involved with calling Realm() multiple times, so it's pretty efficient to do so.

Answer (score 2):

You can use dictionary of realms for threads, something like this:

```
class RealmWrapper {

    var realm: Realm? {
        return realmsPool.realmForThread(Thread.current)
    }

    var realmsPool = RealmsPool()
}

class RealmsPool {

    var realms = [Thread: Realm]()

    func realmForThread(_ t: Thread) -> Realm? {

        if let realm = realms[t] {
            return realm
        }

        do {
            let newRealm = try Realm(configuration: config)
            self.realms[t] = newRealm
            return newRealm
        } catch {
            fatalError("\(error)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I like the idea. I've fixed it by making sure I create a single instance of Realm in the main thread once the app is launched. But this solution is nice too.